# How would I repeat or looping img selectors in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slideshow

I'm making a slideshow for practice which looks like below.

```js
$(function skewSlide() {
  myIndex = 4;
  i = (2 * myIndex) - myIndex;
  $(setInterval(function() {
    myIndex--
    n = (myIndex % 4) + 1;
    $('.modelbox img:nth-child('+ n +')').css({
      'clip-path': 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% -110%, -110% 100%, 0 100%)'
    })
    if (n == 1) {
      myIndex = 4;
    }
    console.log(n);
  }, 1000))
})
```

```css
#canvas {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 2560px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.modelbox{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 2560px;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.modelbox img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 120%, 120% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<section id="canvas">
  <div class="modelbox">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/W20a2ZN.jpg" width="100%">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LGaLIEM.jpg" width="100%">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xvuGBMB.jpg" width="100%">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Y2Xsdkr.jpg" width="100%">
  </div>
</section>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Peeling off each of images is working fine. But a issue is I have no idea how would I repeat/looping the images inside of the code.

Right now the images are not looping when it peels all off. It shows just white background after peeling off is done.

My goal is to make the images looping under the last image gets peeled off and it would looks like img-4, img-3, img-2, img-1, img-4, img-3, img-2, img-1 . . .

Is it any ways or tips to loop the images?

Answer (score 3):

That's because after you modified the CSS property of each image  `'clip-path': 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% -110%, -110% 100%, 0 100%)'` by JavaScript, you didn't set it back to original state (which is `clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 120%, 120% 100%, 0 100%);`) at the end of each loop.

When looping stuff, always remember to reset after each loop is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go. If you want with example.

```js
$(function skewSlide() {
  var imgIndex = 0;
  var countImage = $(".modelbox img").length + 1;
      
  $(setInterval(function() {
      imgIndex++;
      $('.modelbox img:nth-child('+ imgIndex +')').css({'clip-path': 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% 120%, 120% 100%, 0 100%)'});
      
    if (imgIndex >= countImage) 
    {
      imgIndex = 0;
      for(var i=1;i<=4;i++)
      {
          $('.modelbox img:nth-child('+ i +')').css({
            'clip-path': 'polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% -110%, -110% 100%, 0 100%)'
          });
      }
    }
    console.log(imgIndex);
  }, 1000))
})
```

```css
#canvas {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 2560px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.modelbox{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  max-width: 2560px;
  object-fit: cover;
  transition: all 0.8s;
}
.modelbox img {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 1.2s ease-in-out;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 100% -110%, -110% 100%, 0 100%);
}
```

```html
<section id="canvas">
  <div class="modelbox">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/W20a2ZN.jpg" width="100%">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/LGaLIEM.jpg" width="100%">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/xvuGBMB.jpg" width="100%">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/Y2Xsdkr.jpg" width="100%">
  </div>
</section>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
```

Comment: A bit closed but this is not my goal. When it peels off from the 4th image to next, it should show first image.